# using mongrel cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of using a mongrel cluster for a single application?  If you have three instances of mongrel running, I assume that you use apache to load balance and the user connects to a single instance.  But is there any possible improvements to using it for a single application??

Thank you

Comment: You can also use Passenger (http://www.modrails.com/). It's a lot easier to configure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a cluster (i.e. just one single mongrel instance), you can only handle one request at a time. So if ten people try to access your site at the same time, they each have to wait. And if one user does something that triggers a long process, no one else will have access to your site until it's done. So clustering/load balancing is **always** a good idea.

About the only time I wouldn't think it necessary is if you're building a site where there would never be more than one person using it at a time (or if you are totally fine with the potential waits/slow-downs).